# Actionscript 3.0 sound chain

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, chain

Is it possible in actionscript 3.0 to play chain of sounds (i.e. several mp3s)?
Or should I manually start playing first sound, wait for SOUND_COMPLETE event, then start second sound and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use SOUND_COMPLETE, but you should be aware that Flash has some latency issues when it comes to playing sounds.  Additionally, if you're using mp3s you have to remember that the mp3 file format itself has some blank space at the head of the file such that a continuous loop is not possible without using the 10.0+ Sound APIs to extract only the part of the file that contains actual sound.